# How to use Neovim as External editor for Godot (Godot executable permissions)

Tags: vim, permissions, neovim, godot, iterm

I am trying to configure Godot to use launch Neovim in iTerm2 when I double click on a file containing code in the editor, however, a terminal window pops up instead with the following error:

> /Users/myusername/.../Scripts/Player.gd; exit
> zsh: permission denied: /Users/.../Scripts/Player.gd

This error message quickly goes away before I can read it and I am presented with an empty neovim window but it hasn't opened the file I clicked on.  Additionally, the current working directory for the neovim window is my home directory (not the directory the project is based in)

I am running macOS Catalina with iTerm2 and Godot 3.2.2.  My settings to open neovim in

> Editor->Editor Preferences->Text Editor->External:
> "exec path":iTerm2 executable (I tried pointing to the actual nvim executable, but that didn't seem to work).
> exec flags: "nvim {file}".

My understanding is that this should open iTerm and execute the command "nvim [insert filename here]", opening Neovim.

I tried some solutions, including creating a neovim.desktop file, however, nothing seems to work.  If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can give Godot the correct permissions I'd love to hear it.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit of fiddling, I have the info using docs (https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/external_editor.html)
the first value you want is only the executable path. in this case it would be your iterm2 path.

EVERYTHING ELSE GOES IN YOUR FLAGS

Example for me
Exec Path:
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.18.2822.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe

Exec Flags:
powershell -c nvim {file}

I still have to Iron out a few bugs, like the path being interpreted as multiple files (powershell likes paths in quotation marks and I think godot just sends WO them).